# 7zip unzipping fails when destination path is given by parameter [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am automating installation through a Powershell script and am having some issues with unzipping to a path given by a parameter rather than being hardcoded.
The unzipping seems to go like it is supposed to and takes a while to process but in the end no files are delivered to the destination folder. This does not happen when I explicitly state the destination path.

For example, this code works:

```
& $7zipexe x $zipFile -p$zipFilePassword -oC:\Test -y
```

This, however does not:

```
& $7zipexe x $zipFile -p$zipFilePassword -o$path -y
```

where $path is either a parameter taken in through the commandline or explictly stated in the script. Makes no difference. Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I have tried all manner of quotation marks around the parameters but to no avail. $7zipexe, $zipFile and $zipPassword are all taken in as parameters and I have tried to state them explicitly as well. The error is confined to the destination path.

Comment: Is $path a file object (as in the ones returned by Get-ChildItem / Get-Item)? If so, it will be expanded to just the name ('foo' for 'C:\temp\foo') and this will be a problem

Comment: Nope. $path is taken in as a string parameter and when called upon to print the output is "C:\Test", just as inputted.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @Raf, there is no error message. In the shell it seems that everything has been unzipped correctly but when the destination directory is inspected, there is nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
& $7zipexe x $zipFile `-p$zipFilePassword `-o$path -y
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dice. What are the backward slanting accents supposed to do?

Comment: The backtick (`\``) is needed to allow the variable pasted directly onto the parameter (`-p$zipFilePassword` won't work, but `\`-p$zipFilePassword` will). You can also use `"-p$zipFilePassword"` (quotes around entire parameter and argument). Also, you don't say what "no dice" means. I have used this syntax in many PowerShell scripts and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I misplaced the second backtick, placing it at the back of the -p parameter instead of at the front of the -o parameter. Your solution is correct and works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you got it working. As noted you can also use `"-p$zipFilePassword"` and `"-o$path"` if that's easier to read.